# Shopify Timber Framework Drawer .open() changes page position

Tags: shopify

When the drawer opens the position on the page returns to the top.

This is especially frustrating if you have a large product collection and you've added a product to your cart from the bottom of this collection as you're required to scroll back down.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing on JavaScript triggering a scroll to top.

The reason for it, is that it triggers the class `.js-drawer-open` on the `<body>` that has an `overflow: hidden`, which makes it instantly scroll to top and doesn't allow further scrolling.

If you remove that rule, it will not scroll to top by itself, but it will also allow free scrolling while the drawer is open.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Apply `.js-drawer-open` to html tag and remove it from `body`. Scrolling will be disabled on page. And page position will stay at the position where it left.